# Pulling information from another website - Javascript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I'm currently just trying to test and find out how to pull information from [cnn.com](http://www.cnn.com) and get the some of the titles of the articles with the class name, "cd__headline-text." However, when I use the `$.ajax` function to get the titles of the articles on cnn with that class name I get an error that says `response.getElementsByClassName is not a function.`

Below is the code that prompts this error to happen:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
    console.log("hi test");
    $.ajax({
        url: "https://www.cnn.com",
        cache: false,
        success: function(response){
            filter = response.getElementsByClassName("cd__headline-text");
            console.log(filter);
        }
    });

    });
});
```

My current `console.log(response);` output is in this link:

https://pastebin.com/SsBSPdBL

Comment: `console.log(response);` will be your friend

Comment: You need to use [DOMParser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser)

Comment: @ravisachaniya I tried using DOMParser, but it did not work. Instead in the console it showed me this `[prevObject: r.fn.init(100)]`

Answer (score 0):

> However, when I use the $.ajax function to get the titles of the
>   articles on cnn with that class name I get an error that says
>   response.getElementsByClassName is not a function.

Because response is **not a Node or DOM element**.

You need to [parse the XML](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/) and find the element by attribute

```
xmlDoc = $.parseXML( response ),
$xml = $( xmlDoc ),
```

and now get the required value from it

```
$title = $xml.find( "[class='cd__headline-text']" );
```

or

```
$title = $xml.find( ".cd__headline-text" );
```

Or **if the value is already an HTML**, then simply

```
 $( response ).find( ".cd__headline-text" )
```

Comment: The XML did not work, and neither did the HTML value. Could you try doing this with a website, and perhaps demo it and then get back to me if you find out how to do this.

Comment: can you put the `response` value in your question?

Comment: After trying the HTML answer, I get this: [prevObject: r.fn.init(100)]

Comment: Response that you are getting needs to be examined. Add the same in your question, preferably create a snippet of the same using `<>`.

Comment: @RajatKhare Links can be broken, create a snippet here itself. Also, I can't access pastebin.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158659/discussion-between-rajat-khare-and-gurvinder372).

Comment: the response code is too long for me to add as it is 158,000+ characters.

Comment: @RajatKhare I just check the link myself, it is getting redirected to http://edition.cnn.com/ so, may be you just need to change the URL/

Answer (score 0):

Try this, or check [URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21430426/getting-specific-element-from-external-site-using-jquery-ajax)

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
    console.log("hi test");
    $.ajax({
       url: "https://www.cnn.com",
       cache: false,
       success: function(response){
           $(response).find('.cd__headline-text').each(function(){
              console.log($(this).html());
           });
      }
    });
    });
});
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Hi, I tried your suggestion, but nothing gets printed in the console. Do you know why?

Comment: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. I am facing an error on the console while trying your content. check in my [fiddle](https://fiddle.jshell.net/sunildora_94/8qy8bL01/3/)

Comment: Now check I tried my URL, and it's working perfectly. I have given 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' permission in my link.

Comment: so how do I get the titles from cnn.com then?

Comment: check this once- [URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42326777/retrieving-rss-xml-news-data-using-jquery-ajax-in-django)